# Always getting latest version of page item while test is running in sitecore 9.1

Tags: content-testing, experience-optimization

This is regarding the A/B test issue. We have prepared the test with page version 1 with content 1 and page version 2 with content 2. So whenever we browse the page then the content is changing accordingly with the respective test configuration but every time page version showing as 2. due to that I could not able to get the value of the respective version item fields value. every time I'm getting the latest version item value only even it's a different version.

@Sitecore.Context.Item.Version.Number
output: 2 (everytime i'm getting 2 only even it is 1 version)

Any thoughts would be helpful for me. Please share your thoughts

Comment: If you are changing versions via content editor follow like this, https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/switch-between-the-versions-of-an-item.html. If you changing programmatically follow this https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/access-alternate-versions-of-an-item.html.

Comment: I tried that way but none of them is working. Seems it's happening because of A/B test.